# How to find the index of the last duplicated element in the array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with the items duplicated, say for eg:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6]
arr.indexOf(4)  => 3 always gives me the first index of the duplicated element in the array.
```

What is the best approach in finding the index of other duplicated element especially the last one?

Comment: with `lastIndex` ...?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)

> The lastIndexOf() method returns the last index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present. The array is searched backwards, starting at fromIndex.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6];
let index = arr.lastIndexOf(4);

console.log(index)
```

Alternatively, If you want the lastIndex of every duplicate element, you could do

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6];

let lastIndexOfDuplicates = arr.reduce((acc, ele, i, o) => {
  if (o.indexOf(ele) !== i) {
    acc[ele] = i;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(lastIndexOfDuplicates);
```